# How to return nested objects in GraphQL schema language

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I was going through the documentation for GraphQl and realized that the new Schema Langugage supports only default resolvers. Is there a way I can add custom resolvers while using the new Schema Language?

```js
let userObj = {
  id: 1,
  name: "A",
  homeAddress: {
    line1: "Line1",
    line2: "Line2",
    city: "City"
  }
};

let schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    user(id: ID): User
  }

  type User {
    id: ID
    name: String
    address: String 
  }
`);

//I would like User.address to be resolved from the fields in the json response eg. address = Line1, Line2, City
```

This is the schema that I have defined. I would like to add some behavior here that would allow me to parse the address object and return a concatenated string value.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by HagaiCo and in this [github issue](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/499), the right way would be to go with [graphql-tools](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html).

> It has a function called **makeExecutableSchema**, which takes a schema and resolve functions, and then returns an executable schema

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a confusion in here, since you defined that address is String but you send a dictionary to resolve it.

what you can do, is to define a scalar address type:
`scalar AddressType` if you use buildSchema and then attach parse functions to it. (or use [graphql-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tools) to do it easily)

or build the type from scratch like shown in [the official documentations](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlscalartype):

```
var OddType = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'Odd',
  serialize: oddValue,
  parseValue: oddValue,
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    if (ast.kind === Kind.INT) {
      return oddValue(parseInt(ast.value, 10));
    }
    return null;
  }
});

function oddValue(value) {
  return value % 2 === 1 ? value : null;
}
```

and then you can parse the dictionary into a string (parseValue) and otherwise

Comment: Apologies. I have update the question by renaming the 'address' field in the object to 'homeAddress'. So I want that object to resolve into a string. My question is more around how to achieve that with the new schema language

Comment: the new buildSchema still needs to get resolvers attached into the schema, it will define the skeleton but it still needs to know how to parse/deparse/resolve fields

Comment: Yeah that I am aware of. Just wondering if there is way to achieve using the new buildSchema. I like the new syntax as it seems much cleaner.

Comment: as far as i know, you need to iteterate on the fields on the schema and update thier resolve/parse/etc.. you can see example in here: https://github.com/apollostack/graphql-tools/blob/master/src/schemaGenerator.ts#L269 or you can use graphql-tools instead and it will do it for you using that function :)

Comment: Had a look at that repo as well. Would probably go along those lines only if there is no other solution. Upvoting the above comment.